# vb.net - set downloading file a name in chrome

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome

I want to make an application that can download file from chrome and I just need to download file in chrome not another place or webbrowser control in visual basic so I use below code to download the file:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Process.Start("chrome.exe", "http://zbigz.com/file/1c3d3743dcb8f1d438d71fdc3137e0b79aaa4209/2")
End Sub
```

and it will be download. but my main problem is that I can't change downloaded file name before downloading . I checked on "Ask where to save each file before downloading" in chrome setting for downloading files and it will pop-up savefiledialog to get the files name and location. I need to know how to fill these feilds.

if someone has another way to change chrome's downloading file name, notice me.
Thanks

Comment: The simplest thing would be to rename the file, if that is not possible, another choice (from outside vb.net) would be a PHP script that downloads the file - link Google Chrome to the PHP script and voíla! Tell me if you need continuous help.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. It really help me. if you can give an example for php script it will be great. Thanks again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you want to this in PHP you use the following code:

```
<?php
//Filepath is the full url to your file
$filepath="http://www.example.com/examplefile";
//Filename is the name you want to display for the file, even if the files name is "1" you can set the name to be "2"
$filename='Example Name Here';
//The files description:
$filedescription='This is my example file';


//The first line here contains the filetype of the file, so that it can be open correctly.
//This example is .pdf, but you can use other filetypes - as told later on

//This following "block" contains information about the file
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filename); 
    header("Content-Description: $filedescription");             
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filepath));

//Download the file
    readfile($filepath);
?>
```

If your file is not a .pdf, go here for a full list of the different filetypes:
http://webdesign.about.com/od/multimedia/a/mime-types-by-content-type.htm

So if your file is a .jpg, the code should be;

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

instead of;

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
```

So...
What this script will do is that when it opens from a browser, it gets the file you're trying to download and it changes the information before downloading it.
The file could be uploaded to a webserver or (not sure about this) a dropbox account.

VB code should be:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
//The url should be the one to your .php file
    Process.Start("chrome.exe", "http://example.com/example.php")
End Sub
```

I now that this can be quite blurry if you're not used to php and such, but fear not - I will help you!
Just comment if there's something wrong ;)

Comment: Thanks again for your respond. I post my problem for you with my script.

Answer (score 0):

### Very wierd indeed!

**Try to rewrite the page to have a content.**

For now, the page doesn't contain anything but the script.

```
<?php
$filepath="http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/pictures/IDM_title.gif";
$filename='IDM_title.gif';

header('Content-Type: image/gif');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filename);       
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filepath));

readfile($filepath);
?>

<!--A simple html-->
<html>
<header>
<title>Downloading</title>
</header>
<body>
<label>Redirecting to download</label>
</body>
</html>
```

Rename the file to "index.html" and put it in your "muviz.net/download/" folder, then you will be able to go to the address "http://www.muviz.net/download/" and you will download your file! Hopefully ;)